# Conditionally import css packages based on next-themes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using next-themes for dark/light mode on my website and using highlightjs for code highlighting. I want to import a dark variant when the theme is dark and vice versa.
Code:

```
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";    
import "highlight.js/styles/atom-one-light.css";
//import "highlight.js/styles/atom-one-dark.css";
export default function App(){
    const {theme}=useTheme()
    return<div>abc</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If not strict you can try using [prism-react-renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer) for highlighting code

prism-react-renderer dark/light themes:

- duotoneDark
- duotoneLight
- nightOwl
- nightOwlLight
- vsDark
- vsLight

```js
import Highlight, { defaultProps } from "prism-react-renderer";
import nightOwl from 'prism-react-renderer/themes/nightOwl';
import nightOwlLight from 'prism-react-renderer/themes/nightOwlLight';

const { theme } = useTheme();
const mapTheme = {
  light: nightOwlLight,
  dark: nightOwl,
};

return (
  <Highlight
     {...defaultProps}
     theme={mapTheme[theme]}
     code={children.trim()}
     language={language}>
     {/* custom file name, clipboard, highlighting line, line number, ... */}
  </Highlight>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, and my approach would be creating a HOC and pass it a theme prop and then in the HOC I will conditionally import file based on the theme name using 'React.useEffect' hook

You can import file dynamically using bellow code:

```
Import "filepath"
# or lazy import would be like
React.lazy(() => import "filepath")
# additionally you can use async await
await import("filepath")
# or import("filepath").then(()=> {})
```

Check out this [react code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)